# Distributed Java system based on rabbitMQ

Tags: java, spring, rabbitmq

Lets say I have 100 physical servers. Each of them runs a java process. And we have one global rabbitMQ queue. This queue is shared between all 100 processes. In other words I need every of 100 JVMs listen this global queue. 
The first question is is it possible to do it? 
The second question is if it`s possible, how to dispatch messages from the global queue to 100 nodes and make sure that loading will be distributed proportionally, so we will not get the situation when one node loaded up to 100% and other 99 to 0.0005%.

Each node has minimum and maximum capacity. So ideally, one JVM should ask the queue how many items it has. And then grab needed number of items up to it`s maximum capacity. And every JVM from mentioned 100 should do the same. So how to synchronize the queue? How it will let spring amqp on certain machine know that item is ready for procession? How to balance the loading? Thank you

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like sharding to me.  I haven't used it, but there's a plugin for sharding on RabbitMQ now.  https://github.com/rabbitmq/rabbitmq-sharding

Comment: Thank you Jim, but i feel that sharding is not good, because it shards messages from one queues to X queues, but I need to say it that I need 2 messages on queue 1, 4 messages on queue2 and so on. Each consumer should have minimum and maximum capacity. This capacity may change at runtime. So JVM1 takes 3 messages from a queue, then JVM2 takes 5 messages and so on. I would think about having temporary queues for each node, but need to think how to load all nodes proportionally. What do you think about it?

Answer (score 0):

> The first question is is it possible to do it?

Yes, there is no issue.

> how to dispatch messages from the global queue to 100 nodes and make
>   sure that loading will be distributed proportionally, so we will not
>   get the situation when one node loaded up to 100% and other 99 to
>   0.0005%.

RabbitMQ does round robin between consumer on the same queue: `RabbitMQ will send each message to the next consumer, in sequence`. To limit the number of messages sent to a consumer, you can use [consumer prefetch](https://www.rabbitmq.com/consumer-prefetch.html) and set the QoS according to the maximum capacity of the node.  Thus, RabbitMQ will push message to a node as long as the node has not reach its QoS ie. its maximum capacity ie. the number of unacked message is below this threshold.

So the node does not need to know that the queue contains messages, messages will be pushed to the node:

1. Messages are pushed to the node as long as the QoS threshold is not reach.
2. Messages are put in a local queue
3. Once a worker is available, worker takes the message, processes it
4. Worker ackes the message when it finished the process
5. Because the message is acked, the current unacked message is below the QoS threshold, loop to 1).

See:

- The [worker tutorial](https://www.rabbitmq.com/tutorials/tutorial-two-java.html) about round robin and fair dispatching.
- How to set wisely the prefetch [Some queuing theory: throughput, latency and bandwidth](https://www.rabbitmq.com/blog/2012/05/11/some-queuing-theory-throughput-latency-and-bandwidth/)

Comment: Thank you Nicolas! Unfortunately this idea seems doesn't work for me. I need to configure consumer, not MQ. So when MQ sends messages to comsumer1, if it has less than minimum number of items in buffer, it should read the rest from the queue. Also, if consumer has reached it`s maximum number of items, it should reject the message, and the message should go to another consumer. Prefetch in my case should be set for every queue, but even this will not give me ability to control consumers like I'd like to. Please let me know about your ideas. Thank you